# How to check table is empty with count(*)

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am trying to check if a table is empty. I code this method:

```
       public boolean checkIfNULL()
           throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        boolean flag=false;
        System.out.println("Checking if table is empty...");
        String sq = "select count(*) from TABLE1";        
        try {       
            Class.forName(typeDB);
            c = DriverManager.getConnection(path);            
            stm = c.prepareStatement(sq);
            PreparedStatement stm = c.prepareStatement(sq);

            int rowsAffected = stm.executeUpdate();

            if(rowsAffected == 0)
                flag=true;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (stm != null) {
            stm.close();
        }
            if (c != null) {
                    c.close();
        }
        }

        return flag;
   }
```

but sth wrong is hapenning and I get an error message
Query returns results

```
Exceptionn: java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (Connection is closed)
```

How I check the returning value of check?

**UPDATE 1:** 
Instead of the query above, I tried also `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TABLE1)`
but the same is happening..

**UPDATE 2:**
I used this:

```
    ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();

    if(!rs.next())
        flag=true;                  
    else
        System.err.println("ERROR - The table has records...");
```

and it prints the `ERROR - "The table has records..."`. How is this possible? I see the table through SQLite manager and it is empty!

Comment: I'd recommend against this. Normally, I'd recommend some form of `EXISTS` but I don't think SQLite supports that - but I'd still recommend, say, running a basic query with a `LIMIT 1`. You don't need to force the engine to count *every* row if all you care about are the cases "no rows exist" and "at least one row exists". As soon as you've seen *any* row, you know the answer.

Comment: If you post an exception, then please include the full stacktrace, it provides information that may help in tracking down the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing a `SELECT`, so you need to use `executeQuery`, not `executeUpdate`. `executeUpdate` is for statements like `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `INSERT`, `executeQuery` is for executing statements that return a result set (like `SELECT`).

You need to execute a select statement, and do:

```java
try (ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery()) {
    rs.next(); // You always have a row, with the count
    int count = rs.getInt(1);
    flag = count == 0;
}
```

The code in your update won't work, because if you do a `SELECT count(*) FROM table`, then you **always** have one row (with the count).